# SQL dbms_lob.substr extract specific word/text from hugeclob output

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

I'm trying to extract output but the only specific word/text from the huge clob

Like: 'Available' or 'Not Available' or 'Ordered'

This is what i have right now:

```
select dbms_lob.substr( response, 4000, 1) response from (
    select x.* from t_leg x
     where service = upper('LETO87')
     order by search_date desc
) where rownum < 2
```

I try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(response, 30, INSTR(response,' ',10,2)) from 
(select x.* from t_leg x where service=upper('LETO87') order by 
search_date desc) where rownum < 2
```

but i have still some text which i don't need. It is possible to output just the word without the rest of the text?

Comment: Can the specific text appear anywhere in the CLOB?

Comment: HI David, it starts almost in the beginning maybe it is possible to remove some character from left and then the rest after the words?

Comment: If you're looking for specific words near the beginning then you can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`

Comment: thx David, find a way to remove it from the left side but how to remove it also from the right side?

select regexp_replace(response, '(.{29})(.*)','\2\1') response from 
(select x.* from t_leg x where service=upper('LETO87') order by 
search_date desc) where rownum < 2

Comment: Hi @Stef, could you please clarify? Are you trying to get both the specific text from the CLOB as well as the remainder of the CLOB?